# mysql checking if product ID also exist in other table

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have not much experience with JOINS and the result I get with query below isn't correct.
I have a table called **products** and want to check if there are records in the table **product_links**.
I only want to get a list of items that doesn't have rows in **product_links**.

When I run the below query, I only get one line.
Anybody suggestions? Google couldn't help me or I'm searching with the wrong keywords.

```
SELECT a.id, a.SKU, a.title, 
(SELECT COUNT(b.id) AS amount FROM product_links WHERE b.product=a.id) AS amount
FROM products AS a
LEFT JOIN product_links AS b ON b.product=a.id
```

Comment: A hint: take a habit of typing the meaningful part of the question in your browser. For example, typing `mysql get a list of items that doesn't have rows in other table` will get you an answer in an instant.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `not  exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (select 1 from product_links pl where pl.product_id = p.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question i understand you need info of products which doesnt have any links.

Below is the query for that

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM product_links);
```